# Android Studio/gradle error message : cannot access referenceable in javax.naming.referenceable

Tags: java, android, jdbc, derby

I am new to Android Studio & gradle. I have an android project that worked partially in eclipse. The original code uses derby database in Android. The old code connects to derby database directly throuhg JDBC. Due to sheer laziness and practicality, I did not change the database to SQLite. Now I want to change the code to use SQLite  instead of derby and also, I am porting that project into Android Studio. This is where the fun begins.  When I try to run the app, Gradle throws an error saying, " cannot access Referenceable class file for javax.naming.referenceable not found".

Here is the piece of code Gradle is complaining about:

```
package net.jxta.impl.cm.sql;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import net.jxta.impl.util.threads.TaskManager;

import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource;
import org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource;


public class DerbyAdvertisementCache extends JdbcAdvertisementCache {

public DerbyAdvertisementCache(URI storeRoot, String areaName, TaskManager taskManager) throws IOException {
        super(storeRoot, areaName, taskManager);
    }

    public DerbyAdvertisementCache(URI storeRoot, String areaName, TaskManager taskManager, long gcinterval, boolean trackDeltas) throws IOException {
        super(storeRoot, areaName, taskManager, gcinterval, trackDeltas);
    }

    @Override
    protected EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource createDataSource() {
        if(!loadDbDriver( "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to loadDB driver:  org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        }
        EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedConnectionPoolDataSource();
        dataSource.setDatabaseName(dbDir.getAbsolutePath());
        dataSource.setCreateDatabase("create");
        System.err.println("Created derby cache");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected void shutdownDb() throws SQLException {
        // annoyingly, shutting down a derby instance involves catching an exception
        // and checking error codes to make sure it shut down "normally"

        try {
            EmbeddedDataSource dataSource = new EmbeddedDataSource();
            dataSource.setDatabaseName(dbDir.getAbsolutePath());
            dataSource.setShutdownDatabase("shutdown");
            dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            // make sure we get the correct error codes 
            if(e.getErrorCode() != 45000 || !"08006".equals(e.getSQLState())) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Could you guys help me ?
Thanks
D

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with Derby on Android including the absence of the naming support.

See the 08/jan/2010 comment on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DERBY-4458

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for pointing me to this issue. I went through your discussion on Derby on Android and  I am convinced that I will have to change the database to SQLite from Derby.